# Fields and tabs are missing from Run/Debug configurations in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

Used to have tabs Configuration, Code Coverage and Logs. How do I re-enable them [Screenshot of the Run/Debug Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4dlb.png)

This is the exception from the logs

```
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: While loading class org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.lang.resolve.processor.precedence.PrecedenceHelper$UniqueNamesSet: Cannot inherit from final class [Plugin: org.intellij.scala]
```

Comment: Any exceptions in [the log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)?

Comment: @BasLeijdekkers .I have edited the descritpion to include the exception I found in the logs.

Comment: It appears the Scala plugin is causing problems. Try to update or disable it.

Comment: @BasLeijdekkers  Thank you. Unistalling and Re-installing the Scala plug in worked